# How to convert DOS/Windows newline characters to Unix format within GNU Emacs?

Tags: newlines

Is there a way to tell GNU Emacs to convert DOS/Windows newline characters in a file to Unix format?

Comment: You can click on the little button in the modeline and re-save.

Comment: @abo-abo: Which little button?

Comment: The second one from the left, with Unix-style it looks like `:`.

Comment: With DOS, it's `(DOS)`.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If the mode line shows a `(DOS)` indicator, click on it twice to cycle to `:` meaning Unix newlines and then save the file.

If you can't click on the mode line or prefer a keyboard-based solution, run the command `C-x RET f` ([`set-buffer-file-coding-system`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Coding.html#index-C_002dx-RET-f-1722)) and type `unix`. This will change the encoding of newlines without changing the encoding of other characters. (You can also change the encoding of other characters by typing something like `utf-8-unix`.)

Comment: `C-x RET f (set-buffer-file-coding-system)`  --> `M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system RET`

Comment: @CodyChan `C-x RET f` is the default binding for `set-buffer-file-coding-system`.

Comment: I bound a function to `C-x C-m`, and currently I'm using Emacs in terminal remotely, when I execute `C-x RET` in Emacs, it says it is bound to the function I bound to `C-x C-m`, I think `M-x ` suits to everyone.

Comment: @CodyChan I give the default bindings (like the Emacs documentation) because it's useful to most readers. Obviously, if you've changed the default bindings, you can't use the default bindings. You can use `M-x` with the function name which is indicated in parentheses, there's no point in repeating it. Do note that `RET` is the same thing as `C-m`, which is what the Return key sends on a terminal — a binding that only applied to the Return key in a GUI would use `return`.

Comment: If you're like me and want to use the habitual dos2unix command without remembering a new keyboard shortcut, I defined an alias so I can simply type "M-x dos2unix" as "(defun dos2unix() (interactive) (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)".  For unix2dos, subsitute the type for 'dos'.

Answer (score 6):

Save the file, and Emacs will automatically use the correct newline char when writing the buffer to file, according to the value of `buffer-file-coding-system`.

To know what is the value of buffer-file-coding-system, call `describe-variable` then `buffer-file-coding-system`, or run the `describe-coding-system` command which you can do by clicking the second character of the mode line or pressing `C-h C`. To set its value, call `set-buffer-file-coding-system` (`C-x RET f`) and tab to choose the one you want.