# Creating shortcut key for repetitive work

Tags: commands

I create short text files in a folder `c:/Dropbox/daily/` and insert them in various documents using shortcut `C-x i`. I would like to define a shortcut so that I don't have to type the path of folder  again and again while allowing me to choose the file in the folder interactively.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `read-file-name` for that:

```lisp
(defun my-insert-daily (file)
  (interactive (list (read-file-name "Select file: " "c:/Dropbox/daily/")))
  (insert-file-contents-literally file))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x i") #'my-insert-daily)
```

Comment: It works but results in  ^M as an end character in every line. Can it be fixed

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: I am not sure, I don't use Windows. But I guess the one either the answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5800/26163) or [here](https://superuser.com/a/216407) might fix it. Let me know if it does, in which case I can complete the answer.